# How to run GitLab runners on same server as GitLab console

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

GitLab runners seem to require http or https to register the "gitlab-ci coordinator." However, I would like to use the coordinator I currently have installed on the same server. Is there a way to point the gitlab runner to localhost? Is it even possible to use the same machine for both coordinator and runners?

```
# gitlab-runner register
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
127.0.0.1
ERROR: Registering runner... error  runner=****** status=only http or https scheme supported
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

The error is different when I add http/https:

```
# gitlab-runner register
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
http://127.0.0.1/

ERROR: Registering runner... failed   runner=-******* status=
couldn't execute POST against http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/runners: 
Post https://jenkins-master.org:443/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

Comment: have you tried adding http like the error indicated? (`http://127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost`)

Comment: @AviadLevy Yes I have, and still to no avail.

Comment: With `http` still same error? Can you edit your post with the updated output?

Comment: @AviadLevy post edited